# How to get the Federated token of a logged in user - Razor site c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am trying to pass the federated token of a currently logged in user to another microsoft service.

I am user RazorPages and .net Core

I'm accessing my user as so:

```
OnGet{
    var type = this.User.Identity.AuthenticationType; //AuthenticationTypes.Federation
    var token = ????? 
    var credentials =  new VssCredentials(token);


}
```

I'm completely stuck where to get the token from, I've stopped on a breakpoint to inspect the object and not found anything obvious.

Comment: As I suppose you get token from the service after you make the first **Logging in** when you pass password and username, you get a response and there should be a token that you will use later instead of passing password constantly

Answer (score 0):

For `WsFederation`, it will not save the token to User.Identity.

You could try `options.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated` to access token and save it.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                //rest configuration
                options.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated = context => {
                    var token = context.ProtocolMessage.GetToken();
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("token", token));
                    context.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            })
            .AddCookie();
```

And then access the token from `var claims = User.Claims;`